# C++ initialize 2d array in parent class results in bad pointer in child class

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, parent

I am new to coding in c++ and we have to create a tictactoe game for school and with this I have the following problem. I have a parent class Field (which is the playing field and consists of a 2d data array) and a child class ConsoleField (which implements a print method to output on console). We do this so that we can later add another class for a GuiField and use the same game logic but a different print method.

Anyway, my problem is that I want to pass the size of the playing field from the child class constructor to the parent class constructor and initialize the 2d data array. I tried doing this the following way using the constructors initialization list.

```
class ConsoleField : public Field {

public:
    ConsoleField(int size) : Field(size)
    {
    }

    void print() = 0;

};

class Field {

protected:
    int size;
    int** data;

public:
    Field(int size):size(size)
    {
        int** data = new int*[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            data[i] = new int[size];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                data[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    void print () {};

};
```

When debugging I find that the parent class constructor does everything I want it to do and sets its member variable size = size which it gets from the child constructor and also creates a pointer to the data 2d array and initialises the data array with all 0. But when jumping back to the child constructor the member variable data in the child class is not set and its pointer returns 0000000.

How can I use the parent constructor to initialize the 2d array for the child class and get a valid pointer to the data array?

Thanks fo the help.

Answer (score 1):

remove the  `int**`  part from `int** data = new int*[size];`
You do not want to create a new variable on stack but set the class memeber

Comment: Ah, I get it. Thank you! I looked over the code for quite a wihile and don't know how that slipped past me. I should have known that already. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
int** data = new int*[size];
```

This initialized a local variable `data`, not the member variable.

It should simply be:

```
data = new int*[size];
```